# Which file type is this? (similar to JSON)

Tags: json, file-type, dataformat

Which file type is this? It kind of looks like JSON but it is missing the : (colons) and , (commas)

```
"guidedata"
{
    "Hero"      "alchemist"
    "Title"     "Rastla's Alchemist Support"
    "ItemBuild"
    {
        "Items"
        {
            "#DOTA_Item_Build_Starting_Items"
            {
                "item"      "item_tango"
            }
            "#DOTA_Item_Build_Early_Game"
            {
                "item"      "item_boots"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry, I needed to shorten the file content, because I couldn't post the question due to most of the content just being "code".

And maybe is there a tool or something that can help me find this out?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For anyone finding this question and looking for an answer, this is Valve's proprietary KeyValues (VDF) Format: https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/KeyValues